# Show loading animation while Intent is loading

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, runnable

I am trying to create a splash screen that should show a rotating image while the next activity is being loaded.

Therefore I have two activities. The problem is that the rotation does not start, unless I add `Thread.sleep` before the `Intent` is created.

This is the first activity, where the animation should run while the second one loads.

```
import com.silencedut.taskscheduler.Task;
import com.silencedut.taskscheduler.TaskScheduler;

public class LaunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Task<Intent> loader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        loader = new LoadingTask();
        TaskScheduler.execute(loader);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        TaskScheduler.cancelTask(loader);
    }

    private class LoadingTask extends Task<Intent>
    {
        LoadingTask() {
            ImageView imageLoader = findViewById(R.id.imageViewLoader);

            RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(
                    0,360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            rotate.setDuration(5000);
            rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

            imageNeedle.startAnimation(rotate);
        }

        @Override
        public Intent doInBackground() {
            DemoApplication app = (DemoApplication) getApplicationContext();

            return new Intent(app, MainActivity.class);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Intent result) {
            if (result != null) {
                startActivity(result);
            }
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFail(throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            super.onCancel();
        }
    }
}
```

This class uses the [TaskScheduler](https://github.com/SilenceDut/TaskScheduler) library, and the `Task` class is based on `Runnable`.

Inside the second class I add a `Thread.Sleep` to make the loading last more time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try { Thread.sleep(5000); }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { android.util.Log.d("Exception", ex.toString()); }

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My problem is that during these 5 seconds while `MainActivity` is loading, the animated image does not show or rotate. If I copy the same `Thread.sleep` block inside `doInBackground` (`LoadingTask`), then I can see the animation:

```
    @Override
    public Intent doInBackground() {
        DemoApplication app = (DemoApplication) getApplicationContext();

        // this makes the animation run
        try { Thread.sleep(5000); }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { android.util.Log.d("Exception", ex.toString()); }

        return new Intent(app, MainActivity.class);

        return null;
    }
```

So, how do I make it that the animation runs without using an unnecessary `Thread.sleep` inside `doInBackground`? I understand that if the second activity loads quickly, the animation won't show, but it doesn't work even when making it take more time.

Comment: Your first sleep didn't work because it occurred on the UI thread (`onCreate()`). All it did was hang your app. Creating an `Activity` is a UI thread operation. It's expected to be quick, and the new `Activity` is expected to be able to start rendering immediately. Therefor, you shouldn't think of your "loading" work as work that `MainActivity` has to do; it should be done before you ever fire off the `startActivity()`. (Kinda like you did with that 2nd sleep.) Then you somehow pass the result of that "loading" work to `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this Broadcast Receiver.
You don't need to use thread.

Simply start both the activity simultaneously.

In Splash Activity, register for broadcast reciver.and is Second activity send broadcast when all the data loaded. And then finish your splash activity.

If you didn't understand then I can give you an example.
Let me know.

Comment: I don't understand how to start both activity simultaneously. Can you give an example please?